# Adjust search bars width when in mobile view

Tags: html, css

I haven't focused on my website for a long time, I only just noticed that in low resolutions / tablet view that the search bar just floats to the left, but what I really want is the search bar to stretch to match the rest of the design but also to maintain its current form in larger resolutions.

Is this achievable without extensive coding?

website: http://goo.gl/uSD3E5

Answer (score 0):

It is just width css value most be set 100% Like this

```
.footerBar {
    width:100%;
}
```

by this you can view it under any platform.